# Can't see option hierarchy when creating a vocabulary

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

If I create a Taxonomy (vocabulary), I can't see the option hierarchy, what can be the reason of that?

Comment: have you created the terms inside the vocabulary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option have been removed in 6.

Every vocabulary can be hierarchical. If you want to add a child term, just drag it to the right, it will become a child.

[image: child term]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have this vocabulary selected as a "free-tagging" type of vocabulary.  In that case, hierarchy is not relevant.  I had a client who discovered that his hierarchy for a vocabulary had disappeared.  The reason for this was that he'd changed that vocabulary to the free tagging type.

You access this by going to Content > Taxonomy to edit the vocabulary in question.